# Trying to write array to file but have to include a prelude before: Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void writeTextFile(String writeTo, Person people){         
      try{
          FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(writeTo);      
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(wr);
          bw.write(people);
          bw.close();
      }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

I want to write the contents of the array to a file but have to include a prelude which shows the average,minimum and maximum. Whilst doing this i keep getting an error at the `bw.write(people);` any help appreciated?
EDIT: Sorry about the confusion i was wondering why i was getting the error:the method write(int) in the type buffered writer is not applicable for the arguments.

Comment: What error are you getting? You aren't showing any array in your code either.

Comment: "I keep getting an error" - what error? Please don't make us guess. It's not clear whether your question is about the error, or how to include the average/minimum/maximum.

Comment: My guess is you really wanted to use PrintWriter and it would be better write all the data at once instead of opening and closing the file repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedWriter.write()` method can only write certain things not custom objects like `Person`.

```
char[]
int
String
char[], int, int
String, int, int
```

Those are all applicable arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`bw.write()` cant be used for objects.but you can do like this override `toString` method in your class

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
        return "your person class information";

    }
```

then call

```
bw.write(people.toString());
```